Joget parent-child relationship between 2 CRUDs
I have two CRUDs. In one CRUD list (parent) I need a record action that opens the second (child) CRUD list as popup. The records of the child popup CRUD list must have relation with the parent record and if you add record to the child CRUD it must have relation with the parent CRUD logically through some foreign key. How can I achieve this parent-child pattern.

1 - In the parent form, include a button or a link that navigates to the child list. Pass the parent ID as a request parameter in the URL, for example: /childListPage?id_parent={parent_id}
2 - In the child list, modify the Add button to include the id_parent parameter in its URL. Use a distinct parameter name (e.g., id_parent) to avoid conflicts. Example: URL:/childFormPage?&id_parent=<requestParam.id_parent>
3 - In the child form, add a hidden field called id_parent. Set the default value of this field to the id_parent parameter from the URL using a hash variable:#requestParam.id_parent#
4 - When displaying the child list, filter records to show only those related to the current parent. If using a JDBC datalist binder, add a filter condition in the query ex.: SELECT * FROM child_table WHERE c_id_parent = '#requestParam.id_parent#' or if you are using a simple list use the extra filter condition like c_id_parent = '#requestParam.id_parent#'
